# DI/CI Dependency/Constructor injection, how do you know what objects are available?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor-injection, visual-studio-2019

When writing code (C#, Visual Studio 2019), is there any way to tell what the currently available injection options are for your constructor? Intellisense seems unable to help, I usually find myself stumbling across examples to figure out what I can ask for, but there must be a better way to see what objects are provided?

Comment: They are many way to do DI and many libraries depending of the app type you try to make: web, desktop, etc... so the reponse is no.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of DI implementations out there and I would imagine that some of them have tried to improve things in this area, but in the general case, there is not a way to do this.

This problem is widely considered one of the primary drawbacks of dependency injection - the level of indirection and the fact that things aren't wired up until runtime can make it very hard to understand what classes are used and what code actually gets executed when the program runs.

Try to become as familiar as possible with the [composition root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) of your application, and use the debugger liberally to figure out how things are wired up at runtime.